# Is it switch case or animate method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just don't have enough javascript experience to debug this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In the code below I am not sure if my

```
    switch($el_title.innerHTML)
```

or is it my

```
    .animate( style , 400, function() {
```

statement that is incorrect. 
It could be both.

I'm not sure if $el_title.innerHTML is correct.
The corresponding HTML looks like this

```
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="images/Appetizers.jpg">About</a>
    ...
```

I created a style variable to be an object style = {};
I think that's how to make an object variable.
Passing that style variable to .animate doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the complete code:

```
      initEventsSubMenu = function() {
        $menuItems.each(function(i) {
          var $item       = $(this), // the <li>
          $el_title       = $item.children('a:first'),
          el_image        = $el_title.attr('href'),
          $sub_menu       = $item.find('.ac_subitem'),
          $ac_close       = $sub_menu.find('.ac_close'),
          style           = {};

      switch($el_title.innerHTML)
        {
          case 'About':
                       style = {height:'400px',marginTop:'-200px'};
                       break;
          case 'Menu':
                      style = {height:'200px',marginTop:'-150px'};
                      break;
          case 'Take-Out':
                      style = {height:'500px',marginTop:'-250px'};
                      break;
          case 'Gallery':
                      style = {height:'200px',marginTop:'-150px'};
                      break;
          case 'Contact':
                      style = {height:'400px',marginTop:'-200px'};
                      break;
          default:
                      style = {height:'400px',marginTop:'-200px'};
        }

        $el_title.bind('click.Menu', function(e) {
           $.when(toggleMenuItems('down')).done(function(){
              openSubMenu($item, $sub_menu, el_image);
           });
        return false;
        });

        /* closes the submenu */
        $ac_close.bind('click.Menu', function(e) {
          closeSubMenu($sub_menu);
        return false;
        });
      });
    },
        openSubMenu     = function($item, $sub_menu, el_image, style) {
          $sub_menu.stop()
          .animate( style , 400, function() {

              /*
              .animate({
                 height          : '200px',
                 marginTop       : '-150px'
               }, 400, function() { 
              */
```

Also - I know the commented code at the bottom works.
And I am sure my closing braces are fine.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: is $el_title a jquery object? If it is use $el_title.html(), you're using a native method possibly on a wrapped object

Comment: What does the console say after you fix the innerHTML thing?

Comment: I made the change to .html() ... but it still doesn't work. I think it's a combination of both of my issues. Am I setting the style variable correctly? and am I passing the style variable correctly to .animate.

Comment: I apologize but I really don't know how to use the console. Can you see? www.mezzalunari.com/static_pages/home2   Problem is the javascript gets minified on my server. Guess I should figure out how to make it a development environment while debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$el_title` is a jQuery object, but `.innerHTML` is a DOM element property. You should use `$el_title.text()` instead of `$el_title.innerHTML`.

Change:

```
openSubMenu($item, $sub_menu, el_image);
```

to:

openSubMenu($item, $sub_menu, el_image, style);

Comment: I made the change to .text() ... but it still doesn't work. I think it's a combination of both of my issues. Am I setting the style variable correctly? and am I passing the style variable correctly to .animate.

Comment: You're not passing the `style` argument when you call `openSubMenu()`.

Comment: Bingo. You got it Barmar. Thank You.